# I want a UINavigationItem to be a square button with an image. How do i do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to put a square button in the UINavigationBar, much like the + button, but with an image I have. When i do this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings wheel.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(prefsPressed)];
```

It just stretches the image out and makes a long button. Any ideas how to make it square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIBarButtonItem has a [width](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property you can set.  I'm not sure if that will do the trick for you, though.  If not, you can go with creating a custom UIView (e.g. a UIImageView) and setting it using the `initWithCustomView` method:

See here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This works if you first create the button, then set the width, then add it to the navigationBar. I had trouble setting the width previously when I tried after adding the button to the bar.

Comment: The problem with the customview method is that it doesn't look like a navigation buttion. And regardless of when i create the button, it's not letting the width change.